# Как в СИ правильно преобразовать тип константы?

Tags: c

Пробовал преобразовать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define A 15

int main(){
    return strtol(A);
}
```

Но без результата. Как правильно преобразовать тип константы (без printf)?

Comment: strtol принимает три параметра. Более того, первый параметр - указатель на char. Вы же пытаетесь подсунуть ему число. Но даже если допустить, что программа скомпилируется, то она ничего не будет выводить.

Answer (score 3):

Вам уже отвечали: `#define` никаких констант не создаёт! Это просто подстановка текста. Было:

```
#define A 15
puts(A);
```

Станет, непосредственно перед компиляцией:

```
#define A 15
puts(15);
```

Что же касается `strtol`, то не поленитесь заглянуть в man (или что у вас его заменяет):

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

Эта функция вам не подходит: она переводит строку в число, а не наоборот (в том ответе я опечатался, а вы бездумно скопировали ответ в мозг, даже не попытавшить понять о чём речь). Вам нужно не "тип константы преообразовывать" (звучит в данном контексте как абракадабра), а конвертировать число 15 в сишную строку `"15"`, и вот её уже выводить.

Ну и вообще, почитайте какой-нибудь учебник по C. Потому, что судя по вопросам, вы не знаете самых-самых основ, а без них можно долго тыкаться наугад.